# How to convert a column containing list into separate column in pandas data-frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, multiple-columns

I've a data frame and one of its columns contains a list.

```
             A         B
0            5    [3, 4]
1            4    [1, 1]
2            1    [7, 7]
3            3    [0, 2]
4            5    [3, 3]
5            4    [2, 2]
```

The output should look like this:

```
             A      x    y
0            5      3    4
1            4      1    1
2            1      7    7
3            3      0    2
4            5      3    3
5            4      2    2
```

I have tried these options that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35491399/10160150) but its not working.

Comment: `df[['A']].join(pd.DataFrame(df.B.values.tolist(),columns=['x','y'],index=df.index))` the same solution works for me.if not please edit the question with more details

Comment: Nah it gave this error: "Shape of passed values is (1, 14316), indices imply (2, 14316)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"A":[0,1],
                       "B":[[3,4],[1,1]]})
df['x'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x:x[0])
df['y'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x:x[1])
df.drop(['B'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

```
    A   x   y
0   0   3   4
1   1   1   1
```

## Incase the list is stored as string

```
from ast import literal_eval
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"A":[0,1],
                       "B":['[3,4]','[1,1]']})
df['x'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x:literal_eval(x)[0])
df['y'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x:literal_eval(x)[1])
df.drop(['B'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

## 3rd way credit goes to `@anky_91`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"A":[0,1],
                       "B":['[3,4]','[1,1]']})
df["B"] = df["B"].apply(lambda x :literal_eval(x))
df[['A']].join(pd.DataFrame(df["B"].values.tolist(),columns=['x','y'],index=df.index))
df.drop(["B"],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work.!

Comment: what is a error?

Comment: Instead of list items, it gave "[" in the column "X"

Comment: @astroluv your list is stored as string check solution 2

Comment: @anky_91 you are right for that scenario this solution is not good